# When toggling column visibility in Tabulator column width is incorrect

Tags: javascript, visibility, tabulator

I have Tabulator working with column visibility toggle via a dropdown with checkboxes. Checkbox click call `toggleColumn()` which works however the width of the column doesn't update correctly for every row and the header (i.e. for some rows the now visible column width is wider and for some narrower). Only after changing the column width manually does the width align for all rows and the header. What am I missing? Thanks!

Comment: It is hard to diagnose your issue without seeing how your table is setup, could you create a JS Fiddle or Code Pen to demonstrate your problem

Comment: Hi Oli, I am not sure how to create JS Fiddle to demonstrate the problem since the table is part of a larger system and uses Ajax URL and that page requires other pages and libraries. I can however attached the table code and a screen shot of how it looks after toggling a column to be visible. would that help? How do I add the code here?

Comment: some screenshots and your table constructor would be great, thanks

Comment: Hi Oli, I don't know how to upload to Stack Overflow so here is a link to a docx that have the code snippet and the screenshots. Thanks! https://ufile.io/s62eu

Comment: BTW Oli, this is the same table that has the issue of very slow and/or jerky scrollbar. I posted the question on GitHub. It will be hard to put the code on JFiddle since it depends on various files. Thanks!